# Отправление письма на почту автоматический PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Мне нужно отправить сообщение нескольким людям на почту. И после отправления этого письма , через 24 часов автоматический должно отправиться еще одно письмо этим людям. Понятие не имею как это сделать и с чего начать

Comment: Написать скрипт который отправляет письма, создать cron который будет запускать скрипт в нужное время и отправлять письма.

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком абстрактный, сложно посоветовать что-то конкретное.

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, что скрипт отправки письма у вас уже написан. В таком случае, вам после успешной отправки необходимо сохранять куда-либо (лучше в БД) с указанием кому отправлено и в какое время (две колонки в таблице). Затем необходимо написать скрипт, который будет получать из БД всех получателей, у которых дата отправки стоит раньше чем 24 часа назад и которым не отправлено повторное письмо, отправлять повторное письмо и заносить информацию в БД что ему отправлено повторное письмо (третья колонка в таблице). А уже на самом хостинге\сервере настроить запуск этого скрипта раз в минуту\час\два\день с помощью cron

Answer (score 0):

Либо интегировать с сервисом email-рассылок ваш скрипт. Их достаточно много (getresponse, unisender и т.д.). У большинства сервисов есть API. 
Скриптом подписываете на рассылку, которую уже настраиваете индивидуально (цепочки писем, автоответчики, транзакционные письма (когда можно отправить письмо в ответ на действие клиента - прочитал письмо, перешел по ссылке или не открывал в течение недели))